# Looking to Pass Values via a trigger from One table to a second table before they are deleted in the first

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-delete

I have a table that will periodically have records deleted from it. In that instance I want to update a second Master Data table to show the table name and the user name that was recently deleted.

Here is the code from the trigger I am currently using

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Delete_Trig]
  ON [dbo].[firsttable] FOR DELETE
AS BEGIN
Declare @username int, @TableName varchar(200),

SET @TableName='FIRSTTABLE'

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.MASTERTABLE 
               WHERE TABLENAME=@TableName AND USERNAME=@username)
   INSERT INTO
       dbo.tblMasterDataEvents (TABLENAME,  USERNAME) 
          VALUES (@TableName,@username)
```

This works fine when I use a similar process for Insert and Update Statements, but with Delete I am turning up a Null Value. What do I need to do in order to pass that username before it is deleted from the first table?

Comment: You should be referencing the deleted virtual table. You should be using the inserted virtual table in your insert triggers and either/both in your update triggers. The bigger issue I see is that you have scalar variables here which is a good sign that your code has a MAJOR flaw. It needs to handle multiple row operations instead of single row only.

Comment: What is UserName?   A column in firsttable?   Your code declares it, but makes no attempt to populate it before inserting it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change your entire trigger to something like this.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblMasterDataEvents (TABLENAME,  USERNAME) 
select TableName
    , UserName
from inserted i
where not exists
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.MASTERTABLE mt
    WHERE mt.TABLENAME = i.TableName 
        AND mt.USERNAME = i.username
)
```